# How to work with my own dataset of images in sklearn

Tags: dataset, scikit-learn, classification, cluster-analysis

I have a series of handwritten docs (more that 1000) that I want to classify using clustering. The problem I have is that I don't know how to manage the information to convert it into a dataset that I can use. I've looked at the sklearn website info, the tutorials and so on and I know that I need to use the method fit, but I'm lost from here...

Comment: And I'm lost on what your question is.

Comment: What I can infer from your question and its title,  maybe what you are looking for is an optical character recognition (OCR) procedure to extract the text from the "scanned" images?
Moreover, it seems you do not have perfectly clear the goal of your project. You want to classify based on "what"? (topic,length,origin,authors?) Or are you looking for groups? So that you can analyze the similarities between your documents, and then start designing a classifier. For either task, what you are looking for is some basic natural language processing (NLP) techniques, followed by machine learning.

Comment: Sorry, i should have explained better. I wanted to classify the documents by topic but the 20 newsgroup of sklearn is not help, plus the documents are not in English. I want to know if I can classify the documents without extracting the information or if I really need to, they are handwritten so it's difficutl to apply OCR automatically